# XSSFWorkbook write method closing output steam implicitly

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi, xssf, zipoutputstream

Hi I'm uploading msexcel 2007 and after evaluation I'm zipping multiple XSSFWorkbooks to a single zip file. On writing my workbook to file it is implicitly closing outputsteam but I want more entries to be created in zip file.On calling method closeEntry of ZipOutputStream it is throwing exception java.io.IOException: Stream closed.This is my code

```
        // offer the user the option of opening or downloading the
        // resulting Excel file
        // Create the ZIP file
        String outFilename = "review.zip";
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + outFilename);
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                outFilename));
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                String fileName = item.getName();
                System.out.println("filename:- " + fileName);
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = Test.review(fileName,
                        (FileInputStream) item.getInputStream());
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
                workbook.write(out);// This part is closing output stream implicitly

                // Close the entry
                out.closeEntry();// This part is throwing exception

            }
        }
        out.close();
        out.finish();
```

Comment: Can you not just wrap the OutputStream you give to POI in a CloseShielding one?

Comment: Hi I wrapped it like    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(
      new CloseShieldOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
        outFilename)));  but still I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Wrong way round - put the CloseShield one between the real zip stream and what you give to POI